# Magento 2 programmatically create cart rule with condition issue on setOperator

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, programmatically

As per my requirement am creating the cart rule programmatically, for that i am reviewed the following code and implemented in my local

```
public function createRule()
{
    $price = 100;
    $sku = '24-WG085';
    $discount = ($price - (($price + 1) / 2));
    $shoppingCartPriceRule = $this->ruleFactory->create();

    $shoppingCartPriceRule->setName('Add a second for $1 - ' . $sku)
        ->setDescription('Buy one item at regular price, and receive a second item for just $1.00 more!')
        ->setFromDate('2000-01-01')
        ->setToDate(NULL)
        ->setUsesPerCustomer('0')
        ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3',))
        ->setIsActive('1')
        ->setStopRulesProcessing('0')
        ->setIsAdvanced('1')
        ->setProductIds(NULL)
        ->setSortOrder('1')
        ->setSimpleAction('by_fixed')
        ->setDiscountAmount($discount)
        ->setDiscountQty(NULL)
        ->setDiscountStep('0')
        ->setSimpleFreeShipping('0')
        ->setApplyToShipping('0')
        ->setTimesUsed('0')
        ->setIsRss('0')
        ->setWebsiteIds(array('1',))
        ->setCouponType('1')
        ->setCouponCode(NULL)
        ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);

    $item_found = $this->foundProductRuleFactory->create()
        ->setType('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Found')
        ->setValue(1) // 1 == FOUND
        ->setAggregator('all'); // match ALL conditions
    $shoppingCartPriceRule->getConditions()->addCondition($item_found);

    $conditions = $this->productRuleFactory->create()
        ->setType('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product')
        ->setAttribute('sku')
        ->setOperator('==')
        ->setValue($sku);
    $item_found->addCondition($conditions);

    $actions = $this->productRuleFactory->create()
        ->setType('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product')
        ->setAttribute('sku')
        ->setOperator('==')
        ->setValue($sku);
    $shoppingCartPriceRule->getActions()->addCondition($actions);

    $this->ruleResource->save($shoppingCartPriceRule);
}
```

But, when i execute the code i am getting the **'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setOperator() on null.**

I am not sure what is the exact problem in that setOperator, the following operators are available in core

```
$this->setOperatorOption(
            [
                '==' => __('is'),
                '!=' => __('is not'),
                '>=' => __('equals or greater than'),
                '<=' => __('equals or less than'),
                '>' => __('greater than'),
                '<' => __('less than'),
                '()' => __('is one of'),
                '!()' => __('is not one of'),
            ]
        );
```

Thanks in advance for your support and suggestion

Comment: can you provide use statement of "foundProductRuleFactory" and "productRuleFactory" for example     use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Found;

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer for my question, instead of setAttribute i tried to setData('attribute','sku') it's working fine.

```
$conditions = $this->_productRuleFactory->create()
                    ->setType('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product')
                    ->setData('attribute','sku')
                    ->setData('operator','()')
                    ->setValue($requestedParameters['SKU']);
$item_found->addCondition($conditions);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution was the best for me. Just try to create rule in admin pannel and after that find it in ***salesrule*** table. There you can see "***conditions_serialized***" column and there will be different classes. In my case it was something like this

```
{"type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Combine","attribute":null,"operator":null,"value":"1","is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"all","conditions":
    [
    {"type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Address","attribute":"base_subtotal_with_discount","operator":">=","value":0,"is_value_processed":false},
    {"type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Address","attribute":"base_subtotal_with_discount","operator":"<=","value":600,"is_value_processed":false}

]}
```

Take these classes and include them into your code. Watch for the structure nesting.

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\GroupManagement;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection;

public function createRules()
{    
     /*$this->customerGroupColl is instance of 
       Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection*/
    $customerGroups = $this->customerGroupColl->toOptionArray();
    
    /*"$this->ruleFactory" is 
      Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory instance;*/
    $salesRule = $this->ruleFactory->create();

    // General rule data
    $salesRule->setData(
        [
            'name' => 'some rule name',
            'description' => 'some rule description',
            'is_active' => 1,
            'customer_group_ids' => array_keys($customerGroups), //[0,1,2...]
            'coupon_type' => Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON,
            'simple_action' => Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::BY_PERCENT_ACTION,
            'discount_amount' => 50,
            'discount_step' => 0,
            'stop_rules_processing' => 0,
            'website_ids' => [
                1, 2
            ],
            'store_labels' => [
                0 => 'Label for store with Id=0',
                1 => 'Label for store with Id=1'
            ]
    ]);

    /*including conditions. The required classes for type keys can be found in 
       "conditions_serialized" column*/
    $salesRule->getConditions()->loadArray(
        [
            'type' => Combine::class,
            'attribute' => null,
            'operator' => null,
            'value' => '1',
            'is_value_processed' => null,
            'aggregator' => 'all',
            'conditions' => [
                    [
                        'type' => Address::class,
                        'attribute' => 'base_subtotal_with_discount',
                        'operator' => '>=',
                        'value' => 0,
                        'is_value_processed' => false,
                    ],
                    [
                        'type' => Address::class,
                        'attribute' => 'base_subtotal_with_discount',
                        'operator' => '<=',
                        'value' => 600,
                        'is_value_processed' => false,
                    ]
            ],
        ]
    );

    $salesRule->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code and it working fine.

```
    /**
     * Create a cart rule.
     *
     * @param $customerId
     * @param $subscriptionCode
     * @param $amount
     * @param string $description
     * @throws InputException
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function createCartRule($customerId, $subscriptionCode, $amount, $description = '')
    {
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
        $newRule = $this->rule->create();
        $newRule->setName(__('discount for subscription: %1', $subscriptionCode))
            ->setDescription($description)
            ->setIsAdvanced(true)
            ->setStopRulesProcessing(true)
            ->setDiscountQty(1)
            ->setCustomerGroupIds([$customer->getGroupId()])
            ->setWebsiteIds([$customer->getWebsiteId()])
            ->setIsRss(false)
            ->setUsesPerCoupon(1)
            ->setUsesPerCustomer(1)
            ->setDiscountStep(1)
            ->setCouponType(RuleInterface::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC_COUPON)
            ->setSimpleAction(RuleInterface::DISCOUNT_ACTION_FIXED_AMOUNT_FOR_CART)
            ->setDiscountAmount($amount)
            ->setIsActive(true)
            ->setCondition($this->condition->create()
                ->setConditionType(Combine::class)
                ->setAggregatorType('all')
                ->setValue('1')
                ->setConditions([
                    0 => $this->condition->create()
                        ->setConditionType(CustomerAttributes::class)
                        ->setAttributeName('id')
                        ->setOperator('==')
                        ->setValue($customerId)
                ])
            );
        try {
            $ruleCreate = $this->ruleRepository->save($newRule);
            //If rule generated, Create new Coupon by rule id
            if ($ruleCreate->getRuleId()) {
                $this->createCoupon($ruleCreate->getRuleId(), $subscriptionCode."-".$this->helperData->generateCode());
            }
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->logger->error($exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Used classes.

```
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\ConditionInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\CouponInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\ConditionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine;
use Amasty\Conditions\Model\Rule\Condition\CustomerAttributes;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface;
```